# How to call and use Google Maps Web Servcies in PHP web application?

Tags: php, web-services, google-maps

How to call and use Google Maps Web Servcies in PHP web application ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use google map for my site?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/838142/how-to-use-google-map-for-my-site)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Refer the Google Code here [Using PHP in Google Maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlajax.html)

Comment: Thank you, it is a good reference but I may use different database engines with PHP like Sybase.

Comment: That link is about using the JS API, not the WS API.

Answer (score 1):

If your looking to convert places to mappoints though php look [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlgeocode.html).
Otherwise you probably mean you want to create a google maps api on your site and you actually mean the javascript part, in which case look [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial.html) and [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#map_simple_v3)